# Method taking newest information instead of just updating

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

My new problem is that myMin is equalling the last distance before the numbers are equal instead of the actual minimum. e.g. say the first two numbers I enter are 1 and 2, and the next are 1 and 3, and then 1 and 1. It is saying my minimum is 2.0. This is what I'm supposed to get for the assignment.

Enter number 1: 9

Enter number 2: 1

Enter number 1: 7

Enter number 2: 2

Enter number 1: 4

Enter number 2: 4

The minimum distance is: 5.0.

Enter number 1: 20

Enter number 2: 3

Enter number 1: 23

Enter number 2: 23

5.0 + 17.0 = 22.0

MY CODE:

```
double myMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double Min1,Min2;

while ( !(num1==num2) ) {
    pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
    Min1 = pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
    System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
    num1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
    num2 = in.nextDouble();

    if (num1==num2) {
        System.out.print("\nThe minimum distance is: " + Min1 + "\n\n");
        myMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        num1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
        num2 = in.nextDouble();
        while ( !(num1==num2)) {
        pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
        Min2 = pairsMin(num1,num2,myMin);
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        num1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
        num2 = in.nextDouble();

        if(num1==num2) {

            double totMin = Min1+Min2;
            System.out.print("\n" + Min1 + " + " + Min2 + " = " + totMin +  "\n");
        }
        }
    }
} // end while loop
} // end main method
public static double pairsMin( double num1, double num2, double myMin){
   double dist = Math.abs(num1-num2);
    if ( dist<myMin) { // if dist is smaller than the minimum, then dist will be the new minimum
         myMin = dist;
    }
    return myMin;
}
}
```

Comment: didn't you post this exact question earlier today? (forgive me if I'm wrong, I recall seeing precisely the same question)

Comment: It was the same assignment question, but I had two different questions. The first one was how to only print something once inside of the while loop, and this one was how to make it update myMin instead of just using the last myMin found.

Comment: Well have you tried working from what you got from last question to solve this one? Could you please refactor the code so it would be easier to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the two lines

```
pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
```

to

```
myMin = pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
```

At the moment you are always comparing to `Double.MAX_VALUE` and not to the new minimum value.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I can't believe it was something so simple. I was just making it harder than it actually was.